# Are movement trays legal in Warhammer 40k Tournaments?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I play Tyranids and would like to make it faster for myself to move units of 30 termagants. I only ask this question for tournament play since in a casual game none of my friends would care. I was wondering if I am missing a ruling on this in the BRB or a FAQ and also generally how 40k tournaments handle this.

I am planning on playing in the next Adepticon so I will check with the tournament staff on the legality once the tournament gets closer but I wanted to know if anything in general would stop me from using them before I even pose the question to tournament staff.

Comment: Most tournaments I am aware of ask players to use the original base of the miniature. So, as soon as the bases are on the tray, it should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I've seen on forums and general consensus on the web, there doesn't seem to be any rulings against Movement trays in Warhammer 40K. The only issue it may cause is with certain units with blast radius weaponry. This would possibly deprecate you game if your models are locked in a tray.

However, Termagants should be okay to place in trays as from what I can recall of 40K they don't have blast radius weaponry.
Check [this page](http://www.warseer.com/forums/showthread.php?257924-Are-40k-movement-trays-allowed) and [this page](https://www.reddit.com/r/Warhammer40k/comments/6iguxj/movement_trays_in_8th_edition/) that I found on the matter. They all seem to suggest its legal but not advisable as it could put you at a disadvantage.

Comment: 8th edition has a few weapons with an area of effect like a space marine orbital bombardment or vehicle exploding, but no longer has templates so I felt like this edition was the least likely to have problems with movement trays. Also I wasn't planning on using trays that would give me perfect coherency spacing on my models. I actually intend to cram as many as possible into the smallest space possible.

Comment: I see, that would make sense and like I said I wouldn't see any issues with Termagants period. As they tend to have very simple weaponry. In terms of cramming them into the smallest possible place, is there not a distance limit for models? Like minimum distance between bases? its been so long since I actually played the game, I haven't kept up with the rules.

Comment: I wont be able to stack them on top of each other but friendly models can be within 1" of each other. Enemy models are the only models that I am not allowed to be within 1" of unless I am charging them.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you'd have to check the rules for your individual tournaments, however it's unlikely to be an issue and everyone likes speedier play. Additionally in 8th edition there are no more templates so there is no longer a need for a unit to spread out.

Comment: Avoiding template fire is no longer a reason for a unit to "spread out". There are still plenty of other reasons for using this tactic. :)

Comment: I feel like tactics of spreading out are beyond the breadth of an appropriate answer, however in 8th about the only reason to spread out is to have your unit be near multiple things at once (Characters with Auras, Objectives,etc.) or to block/mix with another unit. There are a lot more instances where clumping is strategically sound (holding objectives, CC, bubble wrapping, area denial, etc)

Comment: I only commented because, as written, your comment, "there is no longer a need for a unit to spread out" is not completely true but I wasn't comfortable making that edit.

Comment: In older editions you NEEDED to stay spread out in case your opponent had any blasts. You no longer need to. You may choose to for tactical reasons on a turn by turn basis, but it's no longer a constant need.